# MQTT data handling when bridge connection is down

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, emq

I have established a MQTT bridge connection between Mosquitto and EMQ.

1) Is the bridge connection between 2 MQTTs always stable?

2) If not, how does it handle the Data Communication when the bridge is down?!

Answer (score 0):

1. We have no idea how stable your network is, so we can't comment on how stable a bridge connection will be. But just like other MQTT connections they are a persistent connection (not per message)
2. It depends... on many things, such as what QOS the messages  are published/consumed at. But with the right settings the messages should be queued on the which ever end of the broker they arrive at and then be pushed over the bridge when it is re-established.

Comment: The right settings? Could you please explain further on this? 
I am using QoS 2, cleansession false. This is taken care on both Mosquitto and EMQ.

Comment: QOS is independent for publish, subscribe and bridges. The bridge needs to have clean session false and better than QOS0

Comment: Yes i have that setup. But if the cleansession is false, then it means its persistent session right? And EMQ doesn't support persistent solution. Any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

The stability of emqx depends on the network status between two mqtt brokers. In the implementation of the emqx bridge, if the connection between emqx and mosquitto is broken, the messages which would be forwarded to mosquitto will be cached in disk or memory, and when the connection is resumed, the cached offline messages will be forwarded to mosquitto.